# jquery hyperlink in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, xhtml, hyperlink

I have the code below which checks if a user is logged in, if they are it echo's out a javascript function `hideLogin()` otherwise it will echo the function `showLogin()` . This works fine on every browser I have tested in, but firefox. The link is not clickable, where as it is in every other browser I tested in.

```
<div id="account">
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
if(loggedIn())
{
    echo "hideLogin();";
}
else
{
    echo "showLogin();";
}
?>  
</script>

</div>
function hideLogin()
{
        $('#accountAccess').html('Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["firstName"]; ?> |  <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>');
}

function showLogin()
{
    $('#accountAccess').html('Welcome Guest | <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="login_link">Login</a>');
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need two functions? Why not echo the "Welcome..." message right away in div? Anyways, <script> belongs into the header, and JavaScript belongs inside the <script> tag (so would echo). The reason for your problem might be loading and execution timing: you should do `echo "$({ hideLogin(); }());` at the very least, to allow document to load first.

Comment: Neither links are clickable, the reason for the two functions is because they are called various times on other pages. The two functions are in a seprate .js file, which is loaded in the head section

Comment: Ah. Makes sense now. To get answers faster, I would probably suggest you split the code in the question into two sections, it got me confused :). From experience, if you cannot click on links, mostly something is obstructing it (like an overlay div with transparent background). Did you try inspecting the area with FireBug? From the looks of it, at least the "logout" link should work, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Your <div id="nav"/> is blocking it (width:100%). Add `<div id="nav" style="height:10px;"...` as a proof and links will start working.

Comment: doh! Works great thanks :) , how do I expect your comment as the answer?

Comment: @Elliot: if you don't mind a tip, if you right-click and choose "Inspect element" and Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools does not show you the element you expected, they will show you what is obstructing it instead. Sometimes I do not believe it myself and try to justify it with the bug in the tools, but lately both of them do fairly good job.

Comment: Arh now I get why, I did try that but it didn't show the element I expected, Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When links are not clickable, most probably something is obstructing it. To verify, right click and choose "inspect element" from the context menu. If it does not show you the link tag, it will show the obstructing "div" or "ul" or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, annoys me how its something so simple! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**. Can you please try this

```
<div id="account">
<!-- No need for script tag <script type="text/javascript">  -->
<?php
if(loggedIn())
{
    echo "hideLogin();";
}
else
{
    echo "showLogin();";
}
?>  
<!-- No need for script tag </script> -->

</div>
function hideLogin()
{
        $('#accountAccess').html('Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["firstName"]; ?> |  <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>');
}

function showLogin()
{
    $('#accountAccess').html('Welcome Guest | <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="login_link">Login</a>');
}
```

Comment: If I dont put it between script tag it will just echo hideLogin();, how does it know its javaScript ?